# How to initialise (not reset) with Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

In Terraform is it possible to:

- declare an AWS SSM Parameter Store resource with a default value (i.e. if the parameter needs to be created then also assign to it, but do not update it if the value in the cloud "drifts");
- trigger a Lambda function immediately after Terraform first creates that Lambda (and not on subsequent Terraform applies when the Lambda already exists);
- or, produce a side-effect only if a particular variable in the configuration has been created/modified since the stored current state.

In other words, using Terraform for continuous deployment, is there some way to initialise an application when its infrastructure is first created, without resetting the application the next time Terraform runs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle#ignore_changes

> The ignore_changes feature is intended to be used when a resource is created with references to data that may change in the future, but should not affect said resource after its creation.

For example, for your SSM parameter:

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "example" {
  name  = "foo"
  type  = "String"
  value = "bar"

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      "value"
    ]
  }
}
```